# Lax-Friedrichs for static Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman eq. without boundary condition

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods

> Background literature: 
>   Kao et al. (2004): "Lax–Friedrichs sweeping scheme for static Hamilton–Jacobi equations", Journal of Computational Physics ([link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999103006016)) and
>   Kao et al. (2005): "The Lax–Friedrichs sweeping method for optimal control problems in continuous and hybrid dynamics", Nonlinear Analysis: Theory, Methods & Applications [link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0362546X05000775)

We want to solve
\begin{align}
rv(x) + H(x,v'(x)) = 0
\end{align}
for $v(x)$ with $r \geq 0$.

Let $x_j \in \Omega = [x_1, x_N]$ with $j = 1,\ldots,N$ and $h = x_j - x_{j-1}$.
Define
\begin{align}
H^{LF}  &= H\left(x,\frac{\Delta v^+ + \Delta v^-}{2h}\right) - \sigma\frac{\Delta v^+ - \Delta v^-}{2h}\\
    &= H\left(x,\frac{v_{j+1} - v_{j} + v_j - v_{j-1}}{2h}\right) - \sigma\frac{v_{j+1} - v_{j} - (v_{j} - v_{j-1})}{2h}\\
    &= H\left(x,\frac{v_{j+1} - v_{j-1}}{2h}\right) - \sigma\frac{v_{j+1} - 2v_{j} + v_{j-1}}{2h}
\end{align}
where $\sigma = \max\left|\frac{\partial H(x,v')}{\partial v'}\right|$.

Now we may update according to
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
0 & = rv_j^{n+1} + H\left(x,\frac{v_{j+1}^n - v_{j-1}^n}{2h}\right) -  \sigma\frac{v_{j+1}^n - 2v_j^{n+1} + v_{j-1}^n}{2h} \\
 \Longleftrightarrow \quad v_j^{n+1} &= \frac{-1}{r+\frac{\sigma}{h}}\left[H\left(x,\frac{v_{j+1}^n - v_{j-1}^n}{2h}\right) -  \sigma\frac{v_{j+1}^n + v_{j-1}^n}{2h}\right]  \quad j = 2,\ldots, N-1
\label{eq:for}
\end{split}
\end{align}

In the 2004 paper they propose
\begin{align}
v_1^{n+1} &= \min\{\max\{2v_2^{n+1}-v_3^{n+1},v_3^{n+1}\}, v_1^n\}\\
v_N^{n+1} &= \min\{\max\{2v_{N-1}^{n+1}-v_{N-2}^{n+1},v_{N-2}^{n+1}\}, v_N^n\}
\end{align}

However, this does not work for me.
Can you hint me to some source where they estimate the boundary by a more sophisticated scheme?

EDIT: I got an idea from Huang et al. (2008): "NUMERICAL BOUNDARY CONDITIONS FOR THE FAST SWEEPING HIGH ORDER WENO METHODS FOR SOLVING THE EIKONAL EQUATION", Journal of Computational Mathematics ([link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/43693542))

They propose two methods. Richardson extrapolation (which I do not get) and a Lax-Wendroff type procedure which I got. Concerning the latter. Take Taylor series to approximate inflow boundary 
\begin{align}
v_1 = v_2 - hv'_2 - \frac{h^2}{2}v''_2.
\end{align}
Now we get $v'_2$ from our original HJB $rv_2 = H(x_2, v'_2)$ and $v''_2$ from taking the derivative of the HJB w.r.t. $x$ which gives us $rv'(x) = H_x(x,v'(x)) + H_{v'(x)}(x,v'(x))v''(x)$.

It works sort of, but the convergence is slow. Now I want to try the Richardson extrapolation. In the paper it says (two dimensional)

> Assume $I_h$ is the numerical solution of the first order fast sweeping scheme
>    with mesh size $h$ at the location $(x^*,y^*)$, which is a grid point in Category III. If we further assume 
>   \begin{align}
> I_h - I = \alpha h + \beta h^2 + \mathcal O(h^3)
> \end{align}
>    with constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$, where $I$ is the exact solution at the location $(x^*,y^*)$, which is reasonable when the exact solution is smooth, then clearly 
>   \begin{align}
> \tilde I_h = \frac{1}{3} I_h - 2 I_{h/2} + \frac{8}{3} I_{h/4}
> \end{align}

I really have no idea where to start here. How would you translate the above into our setting?